# Reading XML file with XmlDocument Nodelist

Tags: c#, xml, object, xmldocument, nodelist

Is there some way to use `SelectSingleNode` without actually entering 'math', 'physics' or 'technologija' so that I could read it with any entry?

So far the reading goes something like this:

```
XmlNodeList nodelist = xd.SelectNodes("/studentai/Evening"); 
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist) 
            {
                Student tc = new Student(); 
                tc.id = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("id").Value;        
                tc.name = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name").Value; 
                XmlNode n = node.SelectSingleNode("grades"); 
                tc.grade1 = n.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText; 
                ...
```

Also, since there are 'Evening' and 'Day' students, should I use another nodelist/foreach (`XmlNodeList nodelist = xd.SelectNodes("/students/Evening");`) to read them, or I can somehow combine `/students/Evening` and `students/Day`?

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<students>

  <Evening id="36453" name="Petras">
    <grades>
      <math>
        <grade1>5</grade1>
        <grade2>7</grade2>
      </math>
      <technologija>
        <grade1>8</grade1>
        <grade2>4</grade2>
      </technologija>
    </grades>
    <average>6.00</average>
  </Evening>

  <Day id="75643" name="Jonas">
    <grades>
      <math>
        <grade1>8</grade1>
        <grade2>7</grade2>
      </math>
      <physics>
        <grade1>7</grade1>
        <grade2>10</grade2>
      </physics>
    </grades>
    <average>8</average>
  </Day>

  <Day id="48843" name="Andrius">
    <grades>
      <math>
        <grade1>5</grade1>
        <grade2>5</grade2>
      </math>
      <physics>
        <grade1>5</grade1>
        <grade2>7</grade2>
      </physics>
    </grades>
    <average>5.50</average>
  </Day>

  <Evening id="56442" name="Antanas">
    <grades>
      <math>
        <grade1>8</grade1>
        <grade2>8</grade2>
      </math>
      <technologija>
        <grade1>8</grade1>
        <grade2>10</grade2>
      </technologija>
    </grades>
    <average>8.50</average>
  </Evening>

</students>
```

Comment: I would suggest using XDocument instead to give you access to linq. Also is this your xml or can your xml structure be changes. Its not your querying that i wrong, its the xml structure leaves much to be desired.

Comment: XML won't change (at least the structure won't, but there could be more students). I have to use everything as it is.The thing I do not know, however, is how should I select the nodes 'math' and 'physics' without really knowing their names (can't enter SelectSingleNode("physics");

Comment: @Calvin Smith Linq is good option. But, is not available in previous VS C# versions ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with XPath.

Really, you should never have counter digits in variables or XML elements, but to work with what you've got, this (or similar) will work with 2 grades / subject.

```
// First loop through each student
foreach( XmlElement ndStudent in xd.SelectNodes( "/students/Evening | /students/Day" ) {
  // Build your object from the data
  Student tc = new Student(); 
  tc.id = ndStudent.GetAttribute( "id" );       
  tc.name = ndStudent.GetAttribute( "id" );       

  // Add in the grades
  foreach( XmlElement ndGrade in ndStudent( "grades/*/grade1" ) ) {
    tc.grade1 = ndGrade.innerText;
  }

  // Add in the grades
  foreach( XmlElement ndGrade in ndStudent( "grades/*/grade2" ) ) {
    tc.grade2 = ndGrade.innerText;
  }
} // end of student loop
```

Comment: You're awesome :) Thanks for the detailed answer. However, can you do a selection like the "grades/*/grade2 using XmlDocument and NodeList?

Comment: You can run SelectNodes on an XmlDocument document or a individual node.  To run on a NodeList, iterate using foreach, as show above.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if my question was too unclear or something, but I finally found out how to properly do it:

First, to get module1 I used `tc.module1 = n.FirstChild.Name;`, and the second one: `tc.module2 = n.LastChild.Name;`

I assume, however, this isn't really a 'correct' way of doing things.

Comment: Right. There are several ways to do the same thing. Check my other answer.